# RabbitMQ and Python - connection can't close

Tags: python, ubuntu, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to use RabbitMQ with Python on an Ubuntu 13 machine.

All seems to work - i.e, the RabbitMQ is up and running. Python has the library (I'm using Pika). Code runs.

But after I use publish and try to close the connection - it will not close.

After I tried py-amqplib I've got the same result. It seems that the queue IS created, but the message is not sent, so publish doesn't block. Only connection.close() blocks.

I believe the problem is with RabbitMQ and not the python libraries.

My Code:

```
import pika

JOBS_QUEUE_NAME = "my.queue"

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue=JOBS_QUEUE_NAME)

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key=JOBS_QUEUE_NAME,
                      body='Hello World!')
print "closing"
connection.close()
print "closed"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, some revelation - if I don't use 'connection.close()' all works just fine. WHY?! And if I don't close, won't that mess up RabbitMQ?

Comment: With RabbitMQ (v2.6.1) and pika (v0.9.5) your code works.

Comment: I switched to Kombu and all works great :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem this week [the connection.close() hung forever].

What I found out that the disk space on / (and /tmp and /var) on the host that runs the RBMQ server was at 100% usage, so apparently the RBMQ server had problems.
 
When I tried to restart the server ('service rabbitmq-server restart') I got [FAIL] and the logs told me nothing...

What I did is:
1. Freed up disk space
2. Killed the server manually (with 'kill -HUP') since the 'service stop' command was also failing
3. Started it (service ... start)

and all is well now.
BTW, the server is VM running Ubuntu 12.04.

HTH,
Amir